# limit the input to specific characters (0,5) only after decimal in edittext

Tags: android, decimal

I have an android app which takes one of the input as days . i have successfully limited the number of input after decimal to one. but i want only 0 or 5 after decimal. because days cannot be 1.3 its has to be 1.5 or 1.0. i am new to android so please explain the logic too.

The code is where i restrict

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

        Pattern mPattern;

        public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
            mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
                if(!matcher.matches())
                    return "";
                return null;
```

and i used it as this

```
txtLdays.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5,1)});
```

Comment: Help pls. i am new to android

Comment: use some logging (Log.d)

Comment: can u please explain further i have never use log.d

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html